# Setting ProGuard to obfuscate only my app's package

Tags: java, android, build, proguard

Trying to obfuscate using ProGuard but getting 3rd party libraries errors, so I'm excluding each package one by one:

```
   -keepclassmembers class android.** {*;}
   -keepclassmembers interface android.** {*;}

   -keepclassmembers class com.google.** {*;}
   -keepclassmembers interface com.google.** {*;}
```

Is there a way to whitelist only my package name?

com.dht.github.myApp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your code you are just keeping class members not whole class.
Use this to keep class as it is.

`-keep class com.google.** {*;}`

`-keep interface com.google.** {*;}`

You also can use this line to only obfuscate your own classes and keep everything else.

`-keep class !com.yourpackage.**,!com.youranotherpackage.** { *; }`

Comment: Well, I thought I could use this to avoid handling proguard rules for each 3rd party library, but they still crash..